# how to diplay my own list in alert dialog box?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PersonalizeSettingsActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
            alertDialog.setView(convertView);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Branches");
            ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            ListViewAdapterBranch adapter = new ListViewAdapterBranch(branchList, getApplicationContext());
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                    Branch branch = branchList.get(position);
                    button2.setText("Branch: "+branch.getName());


                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

here branch list contain the list of item.
now i want to hide or close this custom dialog box when i click on the list item

Answer (score 0):

put a global variable for

```
AlertDialog alert;
```

and when creating the dialogBuilder put

```
 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PersonalizeSettingsActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
        alertDialog.setView(convertView);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Branches");
        ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ListViewAdapterBranch adapter = new ListViewAdapterBranch(branchList, getApplicationContext());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Branch branch = branchList.get(position);
                button2.setText("Branch: "+branch.getName());
alert.dismiss();
            }
        });
alert = alertDialog.create();
        alert .show();
    }
});
```